# How to initialize MongoClient once in Spring Boot and use its methods?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

Hello I am trying to export the `MongoClient` after a successful connection in Spring Boot and I am trying to use it in other files so that I do not have to call the connection every single time that I need to make changes in my MongoDB database.

The connection is pretty simple but the goal would be to connect the application to my database once and then use it wherever I want by importing it in any Java file.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are couple of ways of creating an instance of `MongoClient`, configuring and using it within the Spring Boot application.

**(1) Registering a Mongo Instance using Java-based Metadata:**

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    public @Bean MongoClient mongoClient() {
        return MongoClients.create();
    }
}
```

Usage from `CommandLineRunner`'s `run` method (*all examples are run similarly*):

```
@Autowired 
MongoClient mongoClient;

// Retrieves a document from the "test1" collection and "test" database.
// Note the MongoDB Java Driver API methods are used here.
private void getDocument() {
    MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase("test");
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("test1");
    Document myDoc = collection.find().first();
    System.out.println(myDoc.toJson());
}
```

**(2) Configure using AbstractMongoClientConfiguration class and use with MongoOperations:**

```
@Configuration
public class MongoClientConfiguration extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {

    @Override
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        return MongoClients.create();
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "newDB";
    }
}
```

Note you can set the database name (`newDB`) you can connect to. This configuration is used to work with MongoDB database using Spring Data MongoDB APIs: `MongoOperations` (and its implementation `MongoTemplate`) and the `MongoRepository`.

```
@Autowired 
MongoOperations mongoOps;

// Connects to "newDB" database, and gets a count of all documents in the "test2" collection.
// Uses the MongoOperations interface methods.
private void getCollectionSize() {
    Query query = new Query();
    long n = mongoOps.count(query, "test2");
    System.out.println("Collection size: " + n);
}
```

**(3) Configure using AbstractMongoClientConfiguration class and use with MongoRepository**

Using the same configuration `MongoClientConfiguration` class (*above in topic 2*), but additionally annotate with `@EnableMongoRepositories`. In this case we will use `MongoRepository` interface methods to get collection data as Java objects.

The repository:

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends MongoRepository<Test3, String> {

}
```

The `Test3.java` POJO class representing the `test3` collection's document:

```
public class Test3 {

    private String id;
    private String fld;

    public Test3() {    
    }

    // Getter and setter methods for the two fields
    // Override 'toString' method
    ...
}
```

The following method to get documents and print as Java objects:

```
@Autowired 
MyRepository repository;

// Method to get all the `test3` collection documents as Java objects.
private void getCollectionObjects() {
    List<Test3> list = repository.findAll();
    list.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: Hello where does the ```client``` variable come from when you are using ```MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase("test");``` ?

Comment: This is located in the second code block in the ```getDocument()```  method

Comment: Also how do you use the Autowired ```MongoClient``` in a public static method ?

Comment: Please try searching for: "spring boot how to use the Autowired (MongoClient) in a public static method" . You will find quite a few answers - depends upon your need.

Comment: I've been struggling with the 3rd method for hours and it still says that there is no bean for my repository. Can you help me please? Where shall I declare the @Bean? I'm using java configuration.

Comment: Have you defined the `MyRepository`?

Comment: @alienCY You need the `Test3` POJO class, the `MyRepository` interface, the `MongoClientConfiguration` classes. Then, implement the `CommandLineRunner` interface (can do from the Spring Boot Application's class) - and call the `getCollectionObjects()` from the implemented `run` method. Note this is for the (3) example.

Comment: Do I need to create AbstractMongoClientConfiguration class ?

Comment: @Bug Not necessary, in case you configure the connection in different way.

Answer (score 0):

```
    **Pom Changes :**
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <!-- jpa, crud repository -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
    **Main Application :**
    
    @SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
            MongoAutoConfiguration.class,
            MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class
    })
    public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }
    }
    
**MongoConfig Class :**

@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories({"com.repository.mongo"})
public class MongoConfig {

    private final MongoProperties properties;

    public MongoConfig(MongoProperties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoClient mongo() throws IOException {
        log.info("Creating mongo client. Socket timeout: {}, request timeout: {}",
                properties.getSocketTimeout(), properties.getConnectTimeout()
        );
        MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(properties.getUsername(), properties.getDatabase(), readPassword(properties.getPasswordFilePath()).toCharArray());

        MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .credential(credential)
                .applyToSocketSettings(builder -> builder.readTimeout(properties.getSocketTimeout().intValue(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).connectTimeout(properties.getConnectTimeout().intValue(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
                .applyToClusterSettings(builder ->
                        builder.hosts(Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress(properties.getHost(), properties.getPort()))).requiredReplicaSetName(properties.getReplicaSet()))
                .build();

        return MongoClients.create(settings);
    }


    @Bean
    public MongoDatabase database() throws IOException {
        // Allow POJOs to be (de)serialized
        CodecRegistry extendedRegistry = fromRegistries(
                MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
                fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build())
        );
        return mongo().getDatabase(properties.getDatabase()).withCodecRegistry(extendedRegistry);
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws IOException {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongo(), properties.getDatabase());
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() throws IOException {
        mongo().close();
    }

    private String readPassword(String path) throws IOException {
       // return Files.readString(Paths.get(path));
        return "****";
    }

}
```

Comment: You should mention that this works only if the MongoDB instance runs on localhost.