# How to build or query in spring boot with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongorepository

I am using Spring Boot with MongoDB and I want to execute below query using `MongoRepository`.
Can any explain to me how I execute?

this query in spring-boot

```
find({
    $or: [
       {intent: "A1", itemType: "B1", itemId: "C1", isDeleted: false},
       {intent: "A2", itemType: "B2", itemId: "C2", isDeleted: false},
       {intent: "A3", itemType: "B3", itemId: "C3", isDeleted: false},
    ]
})
```

List is provided by user . 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using Spring Data MongoDB

Comment: Actually i am using spring - boot ,

Comment: If any answer in spring - data you can share

Comment: Please follow https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/ this link

Comment: In this resource they execute simple query

Comment: You can use Spring Data MongoDB's `MongoRepository` or the `MongoTemplate`  APIs to query the MongoDB database from a Spring Boot application. See this post: [How to initialize MongoClient once in spring boot and export it to use its methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61663741/how-to-initialize-mongoclient-once-in-spring-boot-and-export-it-to-use-its-metho/61677205#61677205) _and_ also the [Spring Data MongoDB Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#reference).

Comment: I am using MongoRepository

Comment: @AvneeshKumarSinghal ou mentioned that list will be provided by the user then please share your try on this question.

Comment: I don't know how i build this query . I couldn't  try.

Comment: You can use Query provided by spring https://www.baeldung.com/queries-in-spring-data-mongodb