# How to Configure SpringBootApp with a Mongo Production Database

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, heroku, configuration

I am creating a Spring Boot App with Mongo DB and scratching my head a bit with how to set up the production database configuration.

With a SQL-based Database, I'd be used to setting up a data source bean like this

```
@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource()
{
    DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
    dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:h2:file:C:/temp/test");
    dataSourceBuilder.username("sa");
    dataSourceBuilder.password("");
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();
}
```

However,

1. It doesn't seem to be needed - my local app connects to a spun up instance of mongo db without any explicit configuration.
2. It doesn't seem to be a standard with mongo according to [this post][1]

I figured I'd give it a go to see if it would automagically configure in production, but I'm getting a DataAccessResourceFailureException. Info: heroku, did the mLab MongoDB add on.

I have no problem getting the url and I can certainly throw that in an environment variable, but I'm just not sure what I need to add to my app to configure it.

Comment: See this answer: [How to initialize MongoClient once in spring boot and export it to use its methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61663741/how-to-initialize-mongoclient-once-in-spring-boot-and-export-it-to-use-its-metho/61677205#61677205)

Comment: Also, see Spring Data MongoDB documentation topic [Registering a Mongo Instance by using Java-based Metadata](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.mongo-java-config).

Answer (score 1):

Set values in application.properties file like below

```
spring.data.mongodb.database = ${SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_DATABASE}
spring.data.mongodb.host = ${SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_HOST}
spring.data.mongodb.port = ${SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_PORT}
```

You can use the `@Value` annotation and access the property in whichever Spring bean you're using

```
@Value("${userBucket.path}")
private String userBucketPath;
```

The [Externalized Configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) section of the Spring Boot docs, explains all the details that you might need.