# how to create a mongo connection with AbstractMongoClientConfiguration

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I don't care about the MongoClient method or the method, it doesn't exist in the AbstractMongoClientConfiguration class.
How can the connection be created, when it was extended from the AbstractMongConfiguration class, if the MongoClient method could be imported now, what options?

```
@Override
public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        List<CodecRegistry> codecRegistries = new ArrayList<>();
        codecRegistries.add(CodecRegistries.fromCodecs(new DocumentCodec()));
        codecRegistries.add(CodecRegistries.fromCodecs(new UuidCodec(UuidRepresentation.STANDARD)));
        CodecRegistry codecRegistry = CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(codecRegistries);

        return MongoClients.create(MongoClientSettings.builder()
                                                      .codecRegistry(codecRegistry)
                                                      .applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString(connectionString))
                                                      .build());
}
```

that's how it was before putting the new version

```
 @Override
public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {       
    log.info("Input parameters: ");
    log.info("username: {}", username);
    log.info("password: <hidden>");
    log.info("authentication-database: {}", authenticationDatabase);
    log.info("dbHost: {}", dbHost);
    log.info("dbPort: {}", dbPort);
    log.info("dbName: {}", dbName);

    MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(username, authenticationDatabase, password.toCharArray());
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(dbHost, dbPort), Arrays.asList(credential));

    return mongoClient;
}
```

but it also does not allow to use Mongo does not have the method, what is the new way to create the connection with mongo?

Comment: The following post has information about using the `AbstractMongoClientCOnfiguration` class and create a `MongoClient` instance: [How to initialize MongoClient once in spring boot and export it to use its methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61663741/how-to-initialize-mongoclient-once-in-spring-boot-and-export-it-to-use-its-metho/61677205#61677205)

Comment: the problem is that the MongoClient () classes don't matter to me it's like @Override, it doesn't exist in AbstractMongoClientConfiguration

Comment: `MongoClient` and `MongoClients` classes are defined in [MongoDB Java Driver](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/) (not Spring Data MongoDB).