# Spring data mongodb interface configuration and use of _class field

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm migrating from MySQL to mongodb and wondering about couple of things:

1> when using JpaRepository interface and MySQL i need to provide configuration(in my case in the form of settings in application.properties) for it to work otherwise the application fails with a message saying configuration of DataSource failed... but with MongoRepository the application works without any sort of configuration and the data is saved to the default test db. I'd like to know how and where spring makes the initial configuration of the Driver , db name, user and password to use.

2> All objects saved through MongoRepository contain an additional _class field with FQN of the object,
in section [4.6.2 Type mapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.5.1.RELEASE/reference/html/mongo.core.html) the docs say that it needs to do that because

> the values held inside that property have to be read in correctly when retrieving the object.

which i didnt fully understand and would love an elaboration on. i created a test with User collection and a few documents in it, some with _class and some without(by inserting the objects using the mongoshell) and the test application had no problem retrieving the User objects that didnt have the _class field and printing them to the console. I also changed the _class field for the collections that had it to "" and it still printed them correctly so how does Spring uses it?

Comment: This post has some info about Java based configuring the MongoDB connection and database: [How to initialize MongoClient once in spring boot and export it to use its methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61663741/how-to-initialize-mongoclient-once-in-spring-boot-and-export-it-to-use-its-metho/61677205#61677205). You may want to include the version of Spring Data MongoDB you are trying to use in the post.

Comment: while that post is helpful to better my understanding of how configurations works it doesnt answer my question of how spring auto configures my application to use the test db without me defining the settings manually as required when using MySQL and the JpaRepository interface. im using version 2.3.4

Comment: Spring doesn't auto-configure that. It is the default configuration for MongoDB - is `test` (dbname ). `localhost`, and `27017`. If you dont specify anything those are default. Note Spring still uses the MongoDB Java Driver for the connection.

Comment: Also, the documentation you had referred in your post is of older version. Here is the one for [v2.3](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.3.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#reference).