# Why is mongodb also trying to connect to localhost?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I've set MongoDB up on a EC2 Aw linux server.

The file /etc/mongod.conf is adjusted as follows

```
net:
  port: 21528
  bindIpAll: true
```

My Spring Boot Java application properties

```
spring.data.mongodb.database=province
spring.data.mongodb.port=21528
spring.data.mongodb.host=11.11.11.11
spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation=true
```

From the java application log we see a connection message - "Monitor thread successfully connected to server" however later on we get "Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017".

Why is the application trying to also connect mongo to localhost?

```
2021-09-09 09:48:19,797 INFO  [main] com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.SLF4JLogger: Cluster description not yet available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
2021-09-09 09:48:20,007 INFO  [cluster-ClusterId{value='6139d863a27405046d3c682c', description='null'}-11.11.11.11:21528] com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.SLF4JLogger: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:11}] to 11.11.11.11:21528
2021-09-09 09:48:20,304 INFO  [cluster-ClusterId{value='6139d863a27405046d3c682c', description='null'}-35.182.107.168:51828] com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.SLF4JLogger: Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=35.182.107.168:51828, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=13, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=289853927}
2021-09-09 09:48:20,781 INFO  [main] com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.SLF4JLogger: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:12}] to 11.11.11.11:21528
2021-09-09 09:48:21,655 INFO  [main] org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ExecutorConfigurationSupport: Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-09-09 09:48:21,857 INFO  [main] org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-50000"]
2021-09-09 09:48:21,890 INFO  [main] org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer: Tomcat started on port(s): 50000 (http) with context path ''
2021-09-09 09:48:21,905 INFO  [main] org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger: Started EXECUTE in 5.998 seconds (JVM running for 6.742)
2021-09-09 09:48:21,908 INFO  [main] com.jahtoe.pes.EXECUTE: --------------
2021-09-09 09:48:21,909 INFO  [main] com.jahtoe.pes.EXECUTE:  CommandLineRunner DDS Input File operationType json
2021-09-09 09:48:21,910 INFO  [main] com.jahtoe.pes.EXECUTE: --------------
2021-09-09 09:48:21,915 INFO  [main] com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.SLF4JLogger: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms'}
2021-09-09 09:48:21,921 WARN  [main] org.springframework.data.convert.CustomConversions: Registering converter from class java.time.LocalDateTime to class org.joda.time.LocalDateTime as reading converter although it doesn't convert from a store-supported type! You might want to check your annotation setup at the converter implementation.
2021-09-09 09:48:21,926 WARN  [main] org.springframework.data.convert.CustomConversions: Registering converter from class java.time.LocalDateTime to class org.joda.time.LocalDateTime as reading converter although it doesn't convert from a store-supported type! You might want to check your annotation setup at the converter implementation.
2021-09-09 09:48:21,926 INFO  [cluster-ClusterId{value='6139d865a27405046d3c682d', description='null'}-localhost:27017] com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.SLF4JLogger: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:127)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:63)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65)
    ... 3 common frames omitted
```

**Maven**

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.12.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

**Using Mongo**

```
  public static MongoOperations mongoOps;

  mongoOps = new MongoTemplate(MongoClients.create(), "province");
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with spring or java, but it looks like you eventually create a mongoClient with default arguments which is `localhost:27017`, in other words the mongoClient configuration that you mentioned wasn't applied

Answer (score 0):

It seems your mongoDB connect to right ip and port.

I think you are trying to run your application using localhost:27017

however some process already taken 27017 port so you can't run your application

Comment: I added the code I'm using to create MongoOperations. Perhaps that is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to follow the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61663741/how-to-initialize-mongoclient-once-in-spring-boot-and-use-its-methods) and thie resolved the problem.

```
@Autowired 
  public static MongoClient mongoClient;
  
  @Autowired 
  public static MongoOperations mongoOps;


@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    public @Bean MongoClient mongoClient() {
        return MongoClients.create();
    }
}




@Configuration
public class MongoClientConfiguration extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {

    @Override
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        return MongoClients.create();
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "province";
    }
}
```