# about spring-data-mongodb 3.3.1 can't find class mongoClient

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Spring-data-mongoDB 3.3.1 depend on mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1, but the spring code need class mongoClient and mongoClients[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeCRo.png), the mongo depencies(mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1) code can't find this class,Can someone help me solve this problem？  thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K68f6.png)

Comment: the Spring-data-mongoDB 3.3.1   AbstractMongoClientConfiguration need mongoClient and mongoClients, but mongodb-driver-core can't find this class......

Comment: You can start the [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) - with one dependency "Spring Data MongoDB" - and import it into your IDE. And then try this: [How to initialize MongoClient once in Spring Boot and use its methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61663741/how-to-initialize-mongoclient-once-in-spring-boot-and-use-its-methods/61677205#61677205).

Comment: Depending on your application needs you'll need the `sync` or `reactive` driver as mentioned in the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/3.3.1/reference/html/#upgrading.2-3)

Comment: It is probably late now, but, did you tried: import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient and 
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients?